# python как пропарсить javascript строки?

Tags: python, парсер, bs4, re

Нужно пропарсить js код, и вытащить нужные значения.

```
js = """
"auth_token":"zI1NiJ9.eyJza","app_config":[],"return_auth_hash":null};
"""
```

Как я могу вытащить значение из `auth_token`?
Пытался через re+bs4 но не получилось
Скорее всего ошибка в этой строке

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\\"auth_token\\":\s*\\"(.*?)\\"', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экранировать кавычки в питоне вообще не нужно, если строка у вас в одних кавычках `'`, а внутри строки другие кавычки `"`. Тем более, что экранирование и не будет работать как экранирование при использовании `raw string` (символ `r` перед строкой). А вы даже дважды пытаетесь кавычки экранировать, у вас в шаблоне в итоге просто получаются лишние символы `\\`, которых в самой строке, конечно, нет. Достаточно убрать ненужное экранирование кавычек и всё заработает:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'"auth_token":\s*"(.*?)"', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

Вывод:

```
['zI1NiJ9.eyJza']
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно подпилить эту строку до вида корректного json, и разобрать с помощью соответствующего модуля:

```
js = """
"auth_token":"zI1NiJ9.eyJza","app_config":[],"return_auth_hash":null};
""".strip().rstrip(';')

js = '{' + js

import json

print(json.loads(js)['auth_token'])  # Вывод: zI1NiJ9.eyJza
```

Comment: Я тоже подумал про json, но подумал также, что это наверняка просто кусок js для примера, а так он там в html-е где-нибудь лежит не таким мелким куском. Так то парсить json гораздо приятнее.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через findall:

```py
import re

js = """
"auth_token":"zI1NiJ9.eyJza","app_config":[],"return_auth_hash":null};
"""
p = re.compile("auth_token\":\s*\"(.*?)\"")
m = p.findall(js)
print(m) # ['zI1NiJ9.eyJza']
```

Вы скорее всего и искали через match, в данном случае есть проблемы со строкой из тройных кавычек.